# What this construct does in Bash

Tags: bash

```
$ echo [1,2,"abc",4]
```

Output:

```
c
```

I came across this while trying to pass this string to my Node.js program as an argument. Instead Some weird Bash magic happened. I believe it is explained "somewhere" in lengthy `man bash` but I cannot find anything yet.

Comment: bash doesn't print 'c' on my machine.  It prints '[1,2,"abc",4]'

Comment: @TrevorHickey, sorry, please remove surrounding ticks

Comment: @TrevorHickey You don't have any files named `1`, `,`, `2`, `"`, `a`, `b`, `c`, or `4` in the current directory.

Comment: @exebook Read the section of the man page under "Pattern Matching"

Comment: @chepner: it won't match `"` unless it is escaped, as in `[1,2,\"abc\",4]`  (picky, I know).

Comment: @cdarke Ah, right. Quotes aren't glob metacharaters, so aren't subject to any special treatment inside a bracket expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a single character range glob written in a funny way.

`[abc]` matches one of the characters a, b or c.

`[1,2,"abc",4]` matches one of the characters a, b ,c,1,2,4 or comma, and is equivalent to `[abc124,]`

Since you have a directory named `c`, it matches and gets printed.